# how to get the complete output with spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, output

After launch spark-submit command in Spark , I'm unable to get the complete output, because is too long and the exceed the Cloudera Console output.

How can I configure Spark to get the output in some other place?

I've tried by setting the following in spark-env.sh :

```
export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS=-Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
```

But is not working

Comment: The description of the spark.history.fs.logDirectory parameter on this [site](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) describes that the folder must be a folder in the local filesystem. Therefore I think that it isn't possible to directly add the logs to the HDFS. The HistoryServer will pick the files in this folder and uploads them

Comment: I have tried by modifiying to an existing path but is not working either. I would like to know how to do the appropiate configuration in Spark to get the full output log.

Comment: To an existing path on your local filesystem or in the hdfs?

Comment: An existing path in the local filesystem